# setuid not working as expected in Pop!_OS

Tags: linux, permissions, security, setuid

So I was trying to experiment with `setuid`. As per my understanding it allows users to run the binary with context of the owner.
So I wrote a program in C which does write operation in `/root` directory which only the 'root' user can perform. I compiled it and changed the owner of the binary generated to 'root' and added the `setuid` permission using :

```
$ chmod u+s binary_generated
```

The file permissions look something like this

```
-rwsrwxr-x 1 root root 21112 Jun 29 11:26 binary_generated
```

So now my normal user should be able to execute this binary with root user context and it should allow me to write to `/root` directory.
But it's still giving me `Permission Denied` error:

```
[!!] Fatal Error in main() while opening file: Permission denied
```

I'm using Pop!_Os 20.04 with Linux 5.4.0-7634-generic

I think that it has to do something with security features in Kernel or the OS.

Comment: Does it run properly under, for example, `sudo`? If it's a kernel security feature then it *probably* logs, so you should check the usual syslogs or selinux audit logs.